# Why does the custom HTML block not preserve the HTML characters?

Tags: block-editor, html-editor, troubleshooting, htmlspecialchars-decode

For example it seems that the plain single-quote character `'` (`&#x27;`) is converted to the right ones `’` (`&#8217;`) in the HTML page output. I understand the reason for this in regular Gutenberg blocks, but why does it still need to be done in the custom HTML block? I enable troubleshooting mode and use the Twenty Twenty-One theme and it's still converting.

Here are the different between the input methods:

```html
<p>Paragraph block then converted to html: &#8216;</p>
Custom HTML block: &#8216;
<pre class="wp-block-preformatted">Preformatted block: '</pre>
<pre class="wp-block-code"><code>Code block: '</code></pre>
<pre>Classic block with preformatted style: '</pre>
```

[image]

My goal is to preserve the characters so that I can make [inputs for Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70577729/3416774). A piece of JS is in the post to handle this input.

<sub>FYI: [A piece of JS code is needed to use multiple times with different values and function names. How to do it efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70555213/3416774)</sub>

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins and changed to a default theme to verify the problem is still occurring? [the_content](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6ca73cb6486291824f967322d0dceeb7a123c861/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L243) & [get_the_content](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6ca73cb6486291824f967322d0dceeb7a123c861/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L276) doesn't change the character encoding. Mayve it's 1.) coming from elsewhere in your theme or a plugin or 2.) something related to Gutenberg that's maybe changing the character before it's saved?

Comment: which editor are you referring to, is this the classic editor?

Comment: @admcfajn I enable troubleshooting mode and use the Twenty Twenty-One theme and it's still converting. If that's 2, then how can I investigate this?

Comment: @TomJNowell it's the code editor (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+M), the HTML block, and the classic block

Comment: so the block editor, not the classic editor? The classic editor and the classic block are not the same thing, be crystal clear as this is important

Comment: @TomJNowell I see. I though they share the same core? Also, is the code editor (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+M), the custom HTML block and the code block the same?

Comment: no, the classic block is a block that has a TinyMCE instance, it is not the classic editor. They are similar, but they are most definitely not the same. And no, the HTML block and the code editor may share components but they are not the same. Although I have a very strong suspicion that the answer to your question is that you forgot to HTML decode in your javascript, and that your expectation is unreasonable, and that the behaviour you're observing is not a bug, but correct and well behaved HTML.

Comment: in this case, you need to wrap your syntax in something such as code tags otherwise there is nothing to prevent plugins or features from interpreting quotes as quotes and modifying them to be helpful, e.g the texturize feature

Comment: I would expect that you would have built a cipher block to do this, which would have bypassed this issue completely as well as giving you the option of showing a preview in the editor. A block that just has a text area input would have been enough UI

Comment: @TomJNowell I see. What do you mean about HTML decoding in my js? Do you mean that I need to add decode the string with js? [I already tried that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70582747/3416774), and that led to this question. Can you tell what my expectation is unreasonable? Expecting that the custom HTML block should preserve the characters?

Comment: I've attempted to reproduce your issue on my own site and was unable to reproduce the problem. The behaviour you are describing cannot be replicated in vanilla WordPress. I suspect you have additional code/plugins that is interfering and causing this, or there is a step you have left out, either because it's trivial/obvious, you don't consider it relevant, or you believe you've already eliminated it as a cause. The `’` was not encoded in my tests when using the custom html block.

Comment: I would note though, that the resulting HTML is invalid as `’` should have been encoded, and I would note that any javascript should have decoded it if it was to be used. I would also observe that `’` is not what I get when I use the single quote character on my keyboard as i would in most programming languages aka `'`. We also have no good example input combined with javascript code to test, and there is no output data for your decoding method here or in the stackoverflow question. Nevermind that if it was not encoded it would not be valid HTML, it's supposed to be encoded

Comment: I would focus on double checking your assumptions. Does your decode function actually work and what is it's output? How does it differ from the working version Cypher needs? Are you sure this particular quote character is what you actually want and not a `'` or a `"`? Are you sure that this isn't a plugin trying to implement smart quotes interfering with your markup after the fact? Why does your decoding not decode the character in javascript? There's a lot of assumptions and unanswered questions here, and unchecked steps in the chain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132940/discussion-between-ooker-and-tom-j-nowell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by `wptexturize` and the use of a standard `<div>` to contain your code. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wptexturize/

Instead, markup code as code:

> Text enclosed in the tags `<pre>`, `<code>`, `<kbd>`, `<style>`, `<script>`, and `<tt>` will be skipped. This list of tags can be changed with the `no_texturize_tags` filter.

Note that the HTML block just allows you to insert user defined HTML into the post content, that post content still gets processed, it's a block with HTML, not a ***raw*** arbitrary HTML block, e.g. if you put a shortcode inside it, the shortcode gets processed. A paragraph inside a HTML block is just as much a paragraph as a paragraph inside a paragraph block. Likewise you might discover some tags get stripped out if you don't have the `unfiltered_html` capability

Comment: i have a `<script>` block where wordpress puts `<p></p>` on empty lines and encodes some `&` as `&#038;`.  i don't understand how to prevent wordpress from changing the `&` or why it only happens to some `&` and not others

Comment: @Jayen that has nothing to do with my answer, or this question. If you have a new question you should ask a new question, don't spam other questions that have the same theme. Also stop putting script tags inside html blocks, that's not what they're for, and inline JS inside post content is dangerous and it rightly gets stripped out or escaped by WordPress. The solution to how you do what you're trying to do is _don't_, that's not how you put JS in a post

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand your answer.  You said "Text enclosed in the tags <pre>, <code>, <kbd>, <style>, <script>, and <tt> will be skipped" so now I'm not understanding why the text in my <script> is not being skipped.  Can you tell me how I should put JS in a page?

Comment: not by writing it into a block inside the editor, if you are able to do that then you should consider it a major security risk, lots of questions on the site already ask how to run javascript inside a posts content, I'm not going to repeat them in comments. The original author isn't trying to execute javascript, they're trying to display it as code the same way this site embeds code blocks for viewing